# How to create an AppBar with a bottom coloured border in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, appbar

I would like to create an App Bar like this which has a bottom border as well a tint of shadow which can be done using elevation. Could someone provide a sample code snippet to achieve this

[image: AppBar with Border]

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
AppBar(
   bottom: PreferredSize(
     preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(4.0),
     child: Container(
        color: Colors.orange,
        height: 4.0,
     ),
   )
```

Comment: This requires creating a unnecessary container/widget
Checkout this response -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67933424/8153955

This is much more cleaner, can directly be added to your app theme as well

Answer (score 58):

You can use the AppBar's `shape` property to achieve this:

```dart
AppBar(
  shape: Border(
    bottom: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.orange,
      width: 4
    )
  ),
  elevation: 4,
  /* ... */
)
```

Answer (score 11):

Ideally you should make your own appbar if you want a truly customizable design. Example:

```
class MyAppbar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final Widget title;

  const MyAppbar({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      elevation: 26.0,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
              width: 3.0,
              style: BorderStyle.solid,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: title,
      ),
    );
  }

  final Size preferredSize = const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use a widget in bottom of the AppBar, This is how I did it:

```
appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Soroush!'),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: TextFormField(),
            ),
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight)),
```

Answer (score 1):

Now a  `shadowColor` Property is available in AppBar which you can use easily like this:

`AppBar( shadowColor : Colors.blue )`